# PowerShell - Import-CSV and cross reference

Tags: powershell, csv, import

I am running a script as below:

```
$Users = Import-Csv List.csv

Foreach ($User in $Users) {
 $To = $User.email
 $Name = $User.f_name
 $Domain = $User.l_name
```

I want to be able to check `$user.email` against List2.csv and if it does exist in List2.csv then to skip this email address

The format of csv's is as follows:

```
List.csv is: f_name, l_name, email
List2.csv is: email
```

Another thing, if not too complicated, would be to have wildcard domains in List2.csv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this give you what you want?

```
(Import-Csv List.csv |? {$_.email -notin $(Import-Csv List2.csv).email}).email
```

Essentially you're just both CSVs as arrays and using the `-notin` param to filter.

For wildcards you could experiment with `-notlike`.

Comment: Thank you Jacob, I will try this shortly.

Comment: Thanks - this has done exactly what I wanted it to do.

Comment: @MohamedTarmohamed If you're happy the answer you can [Mark it as Accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).